# Unable to change/edit class attribute/ variable from call back function

Tags: python, callback, thread-safety

I am trying to change an attribute of a class from a callback function but the attribute's value is always equal to the value it was initialized as, i.e to 0.

```
class Rainfall:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rainHalfHourCounter = 0

    def incrementRain(self,channel):
        self.rainHalfHourCounter = self.rainHalfHourCounter + 1
        print "incrementRain ",self.rainHalfHourCounter

    rainfall = Rainfall()
    GPIO.add_event_detect(11, GPIO.BOTH,  callback = rainfall.incrementRain,bouncetime = 200)

    while True:
        print self.rainHalfHourCounter
```

The `incrementRain` function is the callback function. This function is set to an interrupt on one of my RPi gpio pins (but basically is just a callback function). The value changes in the `incrementRain` function but the class attribute won't change and therefore I'm unable to use the `self.rainHalfHourCounter` outside of the `incrementRain` function. The print line in the while loop always prints 0. It never increments. Is this a thread safe problem? Is there maybe a easy solution for this problem?

Any help/short sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you using the incrementRain function and self.rainHalfHourCounter attribute? Can you paste the related code?

Comment: I have updated the code, I use the self.rainHalfHourCounter in multiple places, but just to illustrate, the value of self.rainHalfHourCounter does not change in the while loop. This is my big problem.

Comment: Please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the error. See http://SSCCE.org or http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Comment: @FrancoisWattel, I don't think the problem is with your Rainfall class. Seem the incrementRain function is not being invoked properly. I suspect your GPIO object/module is not calling incrementRain. You need to give us output of your execution for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the respons, I found a solution. I used a background interval apsheduler to store the incrementRain counter and it looks like I did not start the sceduler at the right place in my code. Therefore I could not see the counter incrementing. Difficult to explain but you were right that my problem is not in the Rainfall class. I found this error after I ran the sample code I uploaded and saw that it is actually working. Sorry for not testing it, but I was    quite sure that it was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample usage of your Rainfall.incrementRain as a callback and it works perfectly OK.

```
class Rainfall:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rainHalfHourCounter = 1

    def incrementRain(self,channel):
        self.rainHalfHourCounter = self.rainHalfHourCounter + 1
        print "incrementRain ",self.rainHalfHourCounter


class TestCallback(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.callbacks = []
    def addCallback(self, callback):
        self.callbacks.append(callback)
    def run(self, *args):
        for func in self.callbacks:
            #invoke all callbacks with passed in arguments
            func(*args)

t = TestCallback()
#First call, should output 1
r=Rainfall()
r.incrementRain(None)
t.addCallback(r.incrementRain)

#Callback, should output 2
t.run(None)
```

output:

```
incrementRain  2
incrementRain  3
```

Comment: Thanks for the respons, I found a solution. You were right the sample code is actually correct and this helped me to search for a mistake else where. I did not test my sample code since I was quite sure that it was faulty. Sorry for being a noob...